# UIActivityViewController Copy Ignores imageOrientation

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiimageorientation

When I take a picture with the phone in Portrait mode, using a UIImagePickerController, the UIImage item that is returned has the top of the image facing left and an imageOrientation property of `UIImageOrientationRight ,   // 90 deg  CCW`, which is as expected (I think).

When I share the image via a UIActivityViewController, all activities seem to behave correctly except for the Copy activity. When I paste the image into another application (for instance, Messages), the image seems to be ignoring the imageOrientation property.

Has anyone else seen this / found a workaround?

**Updated with complete code:** (project contains storyboard with a single button mapped to `self.takeImageButton` and `- (IBAction)takeImageAndShare:(id)sender;`)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *takeImageButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)takeImageAndShare:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.takeImageButton;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    NSLog(@"Image Orientation: %li",chosenImage.imageOrientation);

    // Now share the selected image
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[chosenImage] applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.takeImageButton;
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

If you run this code, take a photo with the phone in Portrait (`.imageOrientation` is 3 = `UIImageOrientationRight`) and select share activities like Messages, Save Image, etc., the image orientation is correct. If you select the copy activity, the image that gets pasted elsewhere is rotated (top of the image is to the left).

Submitted as [Radar 19456881](http://openradar.appspot.com/19456881). Complete project is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3676319/OpenRadar/radar19456881activityVCCopyTest.zip).

Answer (score 0):

By Default capture image orientation behavior is UIImageOrientationRight, sp  you have to set capture image orientation is

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

Comment: Since imageOrientation is defined as read-only (`@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIImageOrientation imageOrientation`), where would you capture the orientation? Also, it seems that all other activities available via UIActivityViewController respect the imageOrientation property, so modifying that property would cause other activities to misbehave.

Comment: @JeffV for capture image according  device orientation, you have to set capture image orientation for that otherwise by default it will be UIImageOrientationRight and using above readonly property we are able to get current device orientation so at capture time we set inform the system to what orientation image would be saved in device.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052852/why-does-the-uipasteboard-ignore-the-image-orientation-i-use) post, I decided to create my own copy activity:

```
//
//  PhotoActivityCopy.m
//
//  Created by Jeff Vautin on 1/13/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Jeff Vautin. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PhotoActivityCopy.h"
#import "ImageKit.h"
@import MobileCoreServices;

@interface PhotoActivityCopy ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSData *imageJPEGData;

@end

@implementation PhotoActivityCopy

NSString *PhotoActivityCopyActivityType = @"com.me.uiactivitytype.copy";
NSString *PhotoActivityCopyActivityTitle = @"Copy";

+ (UIActivityCategory)activityCategory
{
    return UIActivityCategoryAction;
}

- (NSString *)activityType
{
    return PhotoActivityCopyActivityType;
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle
{
    return PhotoActivityCopyActivityTitle;
}

- (UIImage *)activityImage
{
    CGSize imageSize;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        imageSize = CGSizeMake(76.0, 76.0);
    } else {
        imageSize = CGSizeMake(60.0, 60.0);
    }

    return [ImageKit imageOfIconCopyWithExportSize:imageSize];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    BOOL canPerform = NO;

    if ([activityItems count] > 1) {
        canPerform = NO;
    } else if ([[activityItems firstObject] isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
        canPerform = YES;
    }

    return canPerform;
}

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{
    self.imageJPEGData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(activityItems[0], 1.0);
}

- (void)performActivity
{
    [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:self.imageJPEGData forPasteboardType:(id)kUTTypeJPEG];
    [self activityDidFinish:YES];
}

@end
```

And then I excluded the native copy activity:

```
PhotoActivityCopy *copyActivity = [[PhotoActivityCopy alloc] init];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[chosenImage] applicationActivities:@[copyActivity]];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];
```